# Reading a response in javascript from JSP

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, response

### I am new in learning AJAX and stuck in the first program. Tried to debug but unable to do so.

Below is my code snippet

----------input-ajax.html-------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HTML PAGE</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var request=null;
    function createRequest(){
        try{
            request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        )catch(e){
            try{
                request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){
                try{
                    request= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }catch(failed){
                    request=null;
                }
            }
        }
        if(request==null){
            alert("Error Creating Request Object");
        }
    }
    function getName(){
        alert("getname called");
        createRequest();
        var url = "showName-ajax.jsp";
        request.open("POST",url,true);
        alert("before");
        request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
        alert("after");
        request.send(null);
    }
    function updatePage(){
        //var newName= request.getResponseHeader("r1");
        var newName= request.responseText;
        var name1 = document.getElementById("name");
        replaceText(name1,newName);
    }
    function replaceText(el, text) {
          if (el != null) {
            clearText(el);
            var newNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            el.appendChild(newNode);
          }
    }

    function clearText(el) {
        if (el != null) {
            if (el.childNodes) {
              for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var childNode = el.childNodes[i];
                el.removeChild(childNode);
              }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>WELCOME <span id="name"> GUEST</span></h1>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="t1">
<input type="button" value="Show Name" onclick="getName();"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

----------showName-ajax.jsp------------

```
<%
    String s1=request.getParameter("t1");
    response.setContentType("text/plain");  
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    response.getWriter().write(s1);       // Write response body.
 %>
```

---

But When I run the program (click on the button) nothing happens. Even the alert message that getName function is called does not appear. PLEASE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
)catch(e){
```

should be

```
}catch(e){
```

This would show up as an error in the console of your browser. Be sure to always check that first if things don't work like they should.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ) instead of a } here:

```
try{
    request= new XMLHttpRequest();
)catch(e){
```

So your function never gets defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
change )catch(e){  to }catch(e){
```

but
why are you creating request object everytime on button click?
you just need to call "createRequest()" only once on page load event.